# The controller with the name 'complatedtabs' is not registered

Tags: angularjs

my controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('portfolio')
    .controller('completedTabsController', completedTabsController);
        function completedTabsController($scope){  

            $scope.go = function(){
                alert("hi");
            };
        }


})();
```

my html

```
<button class="primary-btn add-offline pull-right" ng-click="completedTabsCtrl.openOfflineDealForm()">Add Offline Deal</button>
```

my module.js

```
$stateProvider
      .state('dashboard.portfolio.complatedtabs', {
        url: '/complatedtabs',
        templateUrl: PORTFOLIO_URL + '/complatedtabs/complatedtabs.tpl.html',
        controller: 'complatedtabs',
        controllerAs: 'completedTabsCtrl'
      });
```

But it showing this error

**The controller with the name 'complatedtabs' is not registered.**

How i will fix this??

Comment: should be `completedTabsController` coz `controller('completedTabsController'`

Comment: Sorry i am not getting can you plz explain

Comment: updated as answer. checkout - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41717665/1533666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller name in the route declaration (`complatedtabs`) does not match the controller name in its definition (`completedTabsController`): you should have the same name in both, for instance just change the controller to:

```
 .controller('complatedtabs', completedTabsController);
```

Please also note a possible typo: compl**A**tedtabs

Answer (score 2):

Controller name should be from what you registered with `controller` method. Try like below.

```
$stateProvider
      .state('dashboard.portfolio.complatedtabs', {
        url: '/complatedtabs',
        templateUrl: PORTFOLIO_URL + '/complatedtabs/complatedtabs.tpl.html',
        controller: 'completedTabsController',
        controllerAs: 'completedTabsCtrl'
      });
```

If You are confused and wanted make sure by listing all the registered controllers. Use below code which will give you all the registered controllers and this is a `test` code.

```
   // Test Code
    var appModule = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.controllers = appModule._invokeQueue.filter(function(el){
          return el[0] === "$controllerProvider";
        }).map(function(el){
          return el[2]["0"];
        });
    });

    angular.module('myApp').controller('TestCtrl', function(){});
    angular.module('myApp').controller('TestCtrl2', function(){});
```

Comment: i din't use any ng-app it's like module under this i create this folder

Comment: I gave a simple example to get all the controller names to avoid misleading the controller names